# Combine words using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a python list of lists containing words, that are extracted from the pdf in the image.
The issue is each word has been split to multiple words like

```
['Mr. Aram GABRIELYAN', 'Head of the Department of Atmosphere', 'Protection', 
'Ministry of Nature Protection']
```

but it has to be

```
['Mr. Aram GABRIELYAN', 'Head of the Department of Atmosphere Protection', 
'Ministry of Nature Protection'].
```

ex2:

```
['H.E. Ms. Penelope A. WENSLEY', 'Ambassador and Permanent Representative', 
'Permanent Mission of Australia to the', 'United Nations, New York']
```

it has to be

```
['H.E. Ms. Penelope A. WENSLEY', 'Ambassador and Permanent Representative', 
'Permanent Mission of Australia to the United Nations, New York']
```

As this cant be done using Python regex or any way except using NLP. I want to know will i be able to do it using NLP or not.

Comment: Is there a consistent pattern of which items are to be joined because it does not appear to me there is any indicators of what needs joined and what does not?

Comment: Please also tag post as [python].

Comment: There is no consistent pattern, that is the issue, but if words are joined, it will give a more meaningful word that will be a name of the company or a job title or the name of the department.
more examples:
['Mr. Stephen PAYNE', 'General Manager', 'Greenhouse Response Branch', 'Department of Industry, Tourism and', 'Resources']
output:
['Mr. Stephen PAYNE', 'General Manager', 'Greenhouse Response Branch', 'Department of Industry, Tourism and Resources'], i have joined 'and Resources'

['Ms. Viviane Paquin ','Network Facilitator, Forestry and Natural', 'Ecosytems,]  Ecosytems has to join

Comment: Thank you so much, i learnt a new thing today. I am trying this approach, but the issue is my pdf is like below link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qzaOsxM7oDimtTVP87VkXF36mZS2O-kh-7N3YxKkOBM/edit?usp=sharing

will i be able to do this joining of words splitted and present in multiple lines?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying, that is the issue,i have used lot of tools like spacy, nltk, stanfordnlp, Bert, GPT2 and nothing is working,i have spend so many hours in extracting the pattern like space seperated or any similarities in the layout by checking coordinates of data in the pdf, i have tried more than 15 online tools, i paid money for their subscription also, nothing is working.I also don't know how to do it.There are more than 100 pdf with most of the pdfs with pages greater than 150,so it is difficult to do it manually.I also bought chatgpt plus,and it is also not helping anything.

Comment: I also thought to use chatgpt api, but there is token limit, so i need to call the api multiple times, so, it will cost more money

Comment: Do you have a larger sample set for us to review?  Can you provide the code that you used to extract the data from the PDF(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way:

1. Make the multiple words to a single string.
2. Pass the single string to any NER model, something like [spacy](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/nlp-application-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-python-with-spacy/), [flair](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair#example-1-tag-entities-in-text)
3. If step 2 doesnt work, create a custom NER model, something like [spacy](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-custom-ner-in-spacy-3-5-c9942aab3c91)

Comment: I tried it, at the end, i am looking to segregate data into [person name, job title, department, Affiliation] but after making it as a single string, spacy and flair is unable to divide the string accurately into [person name, job title, department, Affiliation].

Comment: then you need to create a custom NER model, refer step 3